# How to edit a Google App script to save the file name based on input and connect it to google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, google-drive-api

I am working on creating a form that allows others to upload Pdf, and Docx to my Google Drive. I found this Google App script which does what I need but I don't know how to edit the code to change the file name to be base on the user input name.

Also, I am trying to connect it to Google Sheet. What should I edit?

HTML

```
       <form id="myForm" align="center">
        <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
       onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                return false;">
      </form>
      <div id="output"></div>
      <script>
function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}
      </script>
```

App script code

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
        
}

function uploadFiles(form) {
  
  try {
    
    var dropbox = "Work_Collector";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
    
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    
    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
        
    return "File uploaded successfully ";
    
  } catch (error) {
    
    return error.toString();
  }
  
  
}
```

Comment: The question needs more focus (it includes two questions; questions on this site should be specific, in other words, remove one of the questions). Also please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation on [Class `File`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file), you can set the name of a file after creating it from a blob with the `File.setName(name)` method.

#### Modification:

You can do this by simply changing the line:

```js
var file = folder.createFile(blob);
```

to:

```js
var file = folder.createFile(blob).setName(form.myName);
```